# what is an efficient way of applying a function to one column in a group from groupby object?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which has 500K rows in it.

I have following columns:

```
               Symbol      Open      High       Low    Close    Volume

Date                                                                    
01-Aug-2017    AADR   49.8800    49.8800    49.8800    49.8800     790
02-Aug-2017    AADR   49.8432    49.8432    49.8432    49.8432     684
```

I have 2071 symbols in the dataframe:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('Symbol')

>>> len(grouped)

 2071
```

I wanted to apply a rolling mean function only on one column (i.e. Close)
of each group and add the mean values as an extra column in existing dataframe.

I believe I could do following:

```
results = {}
for name, group in grouped:
    ma_col = group[1].Close.ewm(span=10, min_periods=10).mean()
    results[name] = ma_col
```

this gives me dictionary of results which I could then turn into a `DataFrame` to use.

Is there a more efficient (better performance) way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` -

```
df.groupby('Symbol').Close.transform(lambda x: x.ewm(span=10, min_periods=10).mean())
```

Comment: thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ let me try it out, hopefully you got pinged! (I don't even know if I've done it correctly). I'll do a comparison w.r.t performance and see, but certainly this is better syntactically.

Comment: @stucash Performance wise, they would be similar with minor differences, because transform internally loops across groups. I'm not sure how to get across that unfortunately, I can only hide it for you.